# How to link datas between database and Firebase auth system

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I start a simple app with Firebase 3 and Angular 1. 
I have an auth system which is included in Firebase. For the moment I used it to register and login users. I store messages data into the Firebase database.

My question is : how can I link user info from firebase auth service to the firebase database ?

Other question : Is it better to stored users into the DB instead of the auth system ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you add the user info to the database as soon as you register the user in your application. I'm assuming you know how to send data to be saved to Firebase, so you basically do what you are already doing with the message data, but with user data (store it in a "users" object, for example).

Be aware, though, that data such as password is sensitive and should be stored safely in the auth parts of Firebase (i.e. no one has open access to it). Things like email used for log-in and even the UID that Firebase generates are fine to be stored in the database (and a great way to reference them later in your application as you see fit).

Always leave the log-in to be done by Firebase's auth service (even using external services like Facebook you should still use Firebase's along with it).

Comment: Thanks you, it was more simple than I thought. And thanks for your advices !